# size limit gzipinputstream

Tags: java, gzip, gzipinputstream

GZIP has a size limitation of 4GB, got it from http://www.gzip.org/#faq10
There are some patches mentioned in the above link to be able to read a file more than 4gb.

I am using GZIPInputStream to read a .gz file.

And I am able to read sizes more than 4GB also. I know I am mixing up the input stream in java and the actual gzip executable.

But I want to know whether that could be a problem at all?

for example - will there ever be a case where I am not able to read a 6Gb .gz file in java? till now I tried and I faced no issue.

In short, is there a relation between the gzip file size limitation and the gzipinputstream in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, it is important to make the distinction between `gzip` the tool and `gzip` the file format.

The former did not support files larger than 4GB until verison 1.2.4.

The latter is specified in [RFC 1952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt) and has no inherent 4GB limitation.

Java's implementation of RFC 1952 doesn't appear to have any 4GB limitation either. I routinely read large files using `GZIPInputStream` (Java 1.6/1.7), and have never had problems.

Comment: How about versions earlier than java 1.6?

Comment: @Abi: No first-hand experience I am afraid. Try it and see what happens. If it's going to break, you'll discover it pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

This limitation concerns only the gzip program. Therefore if written properly, your application should not have any problem reading / writing files over 4GB.

Yet, keep in mind that people trying to read a 4GB+ file you wrote may meet some problems if they use the gzip program.